# Error 401 Unauthorized - Laravel Sanctum + Oracle 11g Bearer Token in Docker

Tags: oracle11g, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

I am using Laravel v8, Laravel Sanctum v2.15, Oracle 11g, Linux Production Server which contains a Docker to use PHP 8.0.30. and oci8 v3.0.1

The backend is made with Laravel 8 by creating an API using Laravel Sanctum, and the frontend is made with Angular.

The Linux server has a connection configured with Oracle 11g, and the rest is taken by the Laravel project from Docker.

When making a request to an endpoint that is protected by the 'auth:sanctum' middleware, it always gives me a 401 unauthorized.

Locally I have the same technologies except for PHP 8, on my local machine I have PHP 7.3.2 with OCI 2.2.0 and everything works perfectly.

I leave code for some files that I think are important.

File Dockerfile

```
from php:8.0.30-apache

#RUN apt-get install -y unzip
RUN mkdir /opt/oracle \
    && cd /opt/oracle     
    
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qqy git unzip libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libaio1 wget && apt-get clean autoclean && apt-get autoremove --yes &&  rm -rf /var/lib/{apt,dpkg,cache,log}/ 

# ORACLE oci 
RUN mkdir /opt/oracle1 \
    && cd /opt/oracle1     
    
ADD instantclient-basic-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip /opt/oracle1
ADD instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip /opt/oracle1

# Install Oracle Instantclient
RUN  unzip /opt/oracle1/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip -d /opt/oracle1 \
    && unzip /opt/oracle1/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip -d /opt/oracle1 \
    && ln -s /opt/oracle1/instantclient_11_2/libclntsh.so.11.1 /opt/oracle1/instantclient_11_2/libclntsh.so \
    && ln -s /opt/oracle1/instantclient_11_2/libclntshcore.so.11.1 /opt/oracle1/instantclient_11_2/libclntshcore.so \
    && ln -s /opt/oracle1/instantclient_11_2/libocci.so.11.1 /opt/oracle1/instantclient_11_2/libocci.so \
    && rm -rf /opt/oracle1/*.zip
    
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH  /opt/oracle1/instantclient_11_2:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
    
# Install Oracle extensions
RUN echo 'instantclient,/opt/oracle1/instantclient_11_2/' | pecl install oci8-3.0.1  
RUN docker-php-ext-enable oci8 
#RUN oci8  
RUN docker-php-ext-configure pdo_oci --with-pdo-oci=instantclient,/opt/oracle1/instantclient_11_2,11.2 
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_oci 
# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

CMD ["apachectl", "-DFOREGROUND"]
```

File composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "8.0.30",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.15",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.11",
        "yajra/laravel-oci8": "^8",
        "yajra/laravel-pdo-via-oci8": "3.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/Keys.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

File routes > api.php

```
<?php

use App\Helpers\Util;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Admin\UserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\AuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\GlobalParameterController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\RequestController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\ReportController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\ResetPassword\CodeCheckController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\ResetPassword\ForceResetPasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\ResetPassword\ForgotPasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\ResetPassword\ResetPasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\ValidateEmail\SendVerifyEmailController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\ValidateEmail\VerifyEmailController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Account\SendActivationEmailController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Account\ActivateAccountController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Account\CheckIfAccountIsDeletedAccountController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Account\DeleteAccountController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Admin\EmployeeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\HomeController;
use App\Models\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::post('/auth/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('/auth/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);

// Verificacion de email
Route::get('/email/send-verify-email/{email}/{movil}', SendVerifyEmailController::class);
Route::get('/email/verify-email/{token}/{movil}', VerifyEmailController::class);

// Reseteo de contraseña
Route::post('/password/email',  ForgotPasswordController::class);
Route::post('/password/code/check/{movil}', CodeCheckController::class);
Route::post('/password/reset', ResetPasswordController::class);

// Activacion de la cuenta
Route::post('/account/delete', DeleteAccountController::class);
Route::get('/account/send-activation-email/{email}/{movil}', SendActivationEmailController::class);
Route::get('/account/activate-account/{token}/{movil}', ActivateAccountController::class);
Route::get('/account/check-if-account-is-deleted/{email}/{movil}', CheckIfAccountIsDeletedAccountController::class);

// Parametros globales
Route::get('/config/verificar-version-de-la-app', [GlobalParameterController::class, 'checkAppVersion']);

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->group(function () {
    Route::post('/auth/verify-token', [AuthController::class, 'verifyToken']);

    Route::get('/password/check-if-update-password', [ForceResetPasswordController::class, 'checkIfUpdatePassword']);
    Route::post('/password/update-password', [ForceResetPasswordController::class, 'updatePassword']);

    Route::post('/auth/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);

    Route::get('/solicitudes', [RequestController::class, 'index']);
    Route::post('/solicitudes/crear', [RequestController::class, 'store']);

    Route::get('/reportes', [ReportController::class, 'index']);
    Route::post('/reportes/crear', [ReportController::class, 'store']);

    Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'index']);

    Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/usuarios', [UserController::class, 'index'])->middleware('permission:'.User::PERMISSION_TO_SEE_USER_LIST);
        Route::get('/empleados', [EmployeeController::class, 'index'])->middleware('permission:'.User::PERMISSION_TO_SEE_EMPLOYEE_LIST);

        Route::post('/usuarios/validar-email', [UserController::class, 'validarEmail'])->middleware('permission:'.User::PERMISSION_TO_ACTIVATE_ACCOUNTS);

        Route::post('/usuarios/restablecer-contrasenia', [UserController::class, 'resetPassword'])->middleware('permission:'.User::PERMISSION_TO_RESET_PASSWORDS);
    });
});
```

File config > sanctum.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Stateful Domains
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Requests from the following domains / hosts will receive stateful API
    | authentication cookies. Typically, these should include your local
    | and production domains which access your API via a frontend SPA.
    |
    */

    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        env('APP_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
    ))),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sanctum Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array contains the authentication guards that will be checked when
    | Sanctum is trying to authenticate a request. If none of these guards
    | are able to authenticate the request, Sanctum will use the bearer
    | token that's present on an incoming request for authentication.
    |
    */

    'guard' => ['web'],
    // 'guard' => ['api'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Expiration Minutes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value controls the number of minutes until an issued token will be
    | considered expired. If this value is null, personal access tokens do
    | not expire. This won't tweak the lifetime of first-party sessions.
    |
    */

    // 'expiration' => null,
    // 'expiration' => 60 * 24 * 7,
    'expiration' => 10, // 10 minutos

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sanctum Middleware
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When authenticating your first-party SPA with Sanctum you may need to
    | customize some of the middleware Sanctum uses while processing the
    | request. You may change the middleware listed below as required.
    |
    */

    'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ],

];
```

File .env

```
APP_NAME="Laravel"
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:a6GjVaZ997Qn***********=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=http://***.***.***.**/backend/public/index.php

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

# SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=APP_URL=http://***.***.***.**/frontend
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8000,localhost:3000
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost

# DB_CONNECTION=mysql
# DB_HOST=***.***.***.**
# DB_PORT=3306
# DB_DATABASE=*******
# DB_USERNAME=*******
# DB_PASSWORD=*******

DB_CONNECTION=oracle
DB_HOST=***.***.***.**
DB_PORT=1521
DB_DATABASE=*******
DB_USERNAME=*******
DB_PASSWORD=*******

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=*******
MAIL_HOST=*******
MAIL_PORT=*******
MAIL_USERNAME=*******
MAIL_PASSWORD=*******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=*******
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

I think it may be a configuration in Apache, but since I don't manage servers much I didn't want to touch anything.

If you need another code, let me know, thank you very much in advance.

When I make the request to the login route it works fine, but when I want to access a route protected by the middleware it always throws me a 401

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvbj8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ1ZX.png)

Comment: Most likely your stateful domains do not match. Add a debug statement and make sure the frontend domain is part of the sanctum's stateful domains list.

Check out this video I made: https://youtu.be/AJudDioDqew?t=100